# change ssl certificate for push notifications for active apps in App Store

Tags: ios, ssl, apple-push-notifications

I have two apps in App Store. When I published the app, push notifications were active but currently, however they are now not active as I am unable to receive notifications in apps which are downloaded from stores. So I thought of revoking the certificates and then make new one for both of the apps.

So I had a question in mind if this will have any effect on provisioning profile or not ? Do I have to download the profile again?

Do I have to resubmit the app or simply putting .pem file on server will do the act?.

Need some guidacne. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can revoke the old certificates and make new ones. That will be fine with this. And make sure you check the Push Notification Configurations for them. Resubmitting the app wont be needed as everything regarding Push notifications is handled through certificates and your profile.

For safety and remembrance, download the newly made certificates onto your machine and stote them safe.

Other than the new changes in certifications and push notification confidurations, this will not have much major change on your profile.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Do I have to download the provisioning profile as well? what about the push notification configuration you have stated?

Comment: Another thing I want to say, I created the CSR request from a old mac which I don't use any more. when I revoke, will there be any issue if I make CSR from new mac?

Comment: Push Notification Config is about the Push Notification Configurations  that you can set and manage in your apple developer console, i.e by logging in your account on developer.apple.com. Regarding provisioning profile, download it as well. Though I doubt it would make any change because you will be using the same profile after making new certificates, right ?

Comment: No issues. You can create a new CSR from new machine. Just revoke previous ones and go for the new ones.

Comment: yeah...so @iCoder what I deduced...I don't have to download the Provisioning profile then..I just make a new CSR, create .pem file and place that in server will do the act

Comment: Yup. First the CSR, then the certificates. That will do.

Comment: Hi @iCode..I tried revoking the certificate with a new CSR..I used all the process to create the .pem file and now I am unable to send APNS...is it necessary to download the provisioning profile? if yes, will that not a duplicate for previous one?

Comment: If you have made a new profile, change the provisioning profile in your Xcode app settings. Also, if you have made a new profile, then you might have to archive your app using that profile and resubmit it.

Comment: No..I was dumb...I am using the different .pem with same passphrase...Sorry for bothering you. Thanx for the help...

Comment: No Problem at all ! :)